# Decode unicode to string

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, encode

I'm using Pycharm with python2.7 and I have a unicode object

```
u'\u0635\u062d\u064a\u0641\u0629 \u0625\u0645\u0627\u0631\u0627\u062a\u064a\u0629: \u062a\u0641\u0643\u064a\u0643 \u062e\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0633\u062a\u062e\u0628\u0627\u0631\u0627\u062a\u064a\u0629 \u0642\u0637\u0631\u064a\u0629 \u062a\u0646\u0634\u0637 \u0641\u064a \u0623\u0628\u0648\xa0\u0638\u0628\u064a http:\\/\\/t.co\\/ygRZ0pfv7W'
```

and I want to convert it in a normal string but raises me the following error:

```
>>> str2.decode('unicode_escape')
u'\u0635\u062d\u064a\u0641\u0629 \u0625\u0645\u0627\u0631\u0627\u062a\u064a\u0629: \u062a\u0641\u0643\u064a\u0643 \u062e\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0633\u062a\u062e\u0628\u0627\u0631\u0627\u062a\u064a\u0629 \u0642\u0637\u0631\u064a\u0629 \u062a\u0646\u0634\u0637 \u0641\u064a \u0623\u0628\u0648\xa0\u0638\u0628\u064a http:\\/\\/t.co\\/ygRZ0pfv7W'
>>> print str2.decode('unicode_escape')
صحيفة إماراتية: تفكيك خلية استخباراتية قطرية تنشط في أبو ظبي http:\/\/t.co\/ygRZ0pfv7W
>>> str3 = str(str2.decode('unicode_escape'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

what can I do about it?

Comment: Copy and paste the text of your error, not a screenshot of your error.

Comment: so what's the problem? Your screencap clearly shows the string being decoded back into arabic (or whatever that script is) using `str2.decode()`.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? I'm guessing 2.7.x.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I was confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see a problem with your use of `str()`.

First, be sure you understand the concepts of Unicode strings, byte strings, encoding, and decoding. The Python 2.7 doc [**Unicode HOWTO**](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) is a great place to start.

Second, understand that your expression `str2.decode()` is returning a Unicode string. Thus, your expression

```
str3 = str(str2.decode(...))
```

is asking Python to convert that Unicode string into a byte string, using a default encoder. The default encoder is ASCII, which has no way to convert Arabic characters. That is why Python gives you the error message, "'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0..4".

If you want `str3` to be a UTF-8 encoded byte string corresponding to `str2`, try:

```
str3_u = str2.decode(...)
str3   = str3_u.encode('utf8')
```

But, what do you really want to accomplish? If str2 is already a byte string, why are you converting it to a Unicode string and then back to a byte string? There is more to this question.

Update: remove references to including text of error message and Python version, because questioner edited the question to include that info. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is the representation of a unicode string. The representation ensures, that only printable characters are printed. So `u'\u0635` is exactly one character. A character at codepoint 0635.

```
>>> print u'\u0635\u062d\u064a\u0641\u0629 \u0625\u0645\u0627\u0631\u0627\u062a\u064a\u0629: \u062a\u0641\u0643\u064a\u0643 \u062e\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u0627\u0633\u062a\u062e\u0628\u0627\u0631\u0627\u062a\u064a\u0629 \u0642\u0637\u0631\u064a\u0629 \u062a\u0646\u0634\u0637 \u0641\u064a \u0623\u0628\u0648\xa0\u0638\u0628\u064a http:\\/\\/t.co\\/ygRZ0pfv7W'
صحيفة إماراتية: تفكيك خلية استخباراتية قطرية تنشط في أبو ظبي http:\/\/t.co\/ygRZ0pfv7W
```

Comment: Oh that's right. I'm feeling dumb right now. Thanks friend!